# How to Insert at beginning of Singly Linked List

Tags: c++, singly-linked-list

Im trying to insert Node at beginning of list , but unable to , the logic for insert seem to be correct in my opinion

```
void display(Node *t)
{
    Node *p = t;
    while (p != 0)
    {
        cout << p->data << ",";
        p = p->next;
    }
}
void Insert(Node *t,int pos,int x)
{
    Node *temp=NULL;
    if(pos==0)
    {
       temp=new Node;
       temp->data=x;
       temp->next=t;
       t=temp;
    }
}
int main()
{
     Node *p = new Node;
     Node *q = new Node;

     p->data = 4;
     p->next = q;

     q->data=6;
     q->next=NULL;

     Insert(p,0,89);
     Insert(p,0,80);

     display(p);
}
```

I expect output of  **80,89,4,6,**

But the Actual Output I get is **4,6,**

Comment: where is `Node` defined? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: `Insert(t,0,89);` what is `t`?

Comment: "But the Actual Output I get is 4,6," no. Please make sure the code you post is actually doing what you claim

Comment: You've got the details wrong, but you've omitted the details from your posted code. The details matter, please post **complete** code.

Comment: The most important thing to learn about pointers is that there is nothing special about pointers. Assigning to a `Node*` is no different from assigning to an `int`.

Comment: The scope of the pointer t (Node* t) is limited to the function Insert(). Hence your pointer does not exist beyond Insert() function and you are not able to track your allocated memory as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass pointer by reference to Insert:

```
void Insert(Node* &t, int pos, int x)
```

Comment: You don't **need** to do that. In fact it would arguably be better to rewrite as `t = Insert(t,0,89);`

Comment: @john "better" without explanation is the little brother of "you need to" without explanation ;)

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Nicely put, I've modifed my comment (slightly)

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 sometimes :P

Comment: @john also since the return type is void.

Comment: @DevendraSwami Well obviously I'm suggesting that the return type could be changed.

Comment: @john you are right. But the reason is the scope of the Node *t which is with in the Insert function